# Searching and Returning bold values in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I know that this probably isn't the most ideal way to to do this but just bear with me.

I have a document with a few tables on it. I'm using a userform to search the tables/sub-categories and return the relevant values. I want to select the sub categories with a range of option buttons on a userform, these will in turn set the range for the search function to look within. I also want to dynamically update the option buttons if a new table was to be added or anything along those lines.

The only thing that differentiates the title of a sub-category/table, and the items within it, is that the title of a sub-category/table is bold. So what I'm looking to do is search the first column of the spreadsheet and return the names of any entries in bold. These values are then used to set the names of the option buttons :).

The following function is my attempt at finding the text entities in column a that are in bold, returning them and setting each to an individual variable to be used in another function. The `bold1` .... variables are all globally defined variables as I need them in another sub, as is the `page` variable which contains the relevant page to be used. Currently the code returns an error stating "variable or with block not set" and using the debugger I can see that `bold1` .... and all the other boldx variables have no value set. Does anybody know whats going on/how to fix this function.

Thanks in advance :)

```
Sub SelectBold()
    Dim Bcell As Range
    For Each Bcell In Worksheets(Page).Range("A1:A500")
        If Bcell.Font.Bold = True Then
            Set bold1 = Bcell
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

EDIT: I simplified the above function, to remove clutter and help narrow in on the issue. I want the above function to store the contents of the found cell (any cell in the document in bold at this stage) in the variable `bold1`

Comment: As u find them , store in an 2d array  (name , row number )

Comment: Sounds like a good idea :), I'll give it a try and report back, I'm still learning so please forgive the poor code.

Comment: When exactly are you getting the error? While executing the `SelectBold` sub or another sub? How and where (module) are the variables declared?

Comment: It isn't giving me an error at this stage, instead it is just storing nothing as the variable `bold1` when I want it to store the term found that is in bold

Answer (score 0):

This will return an array of values from bold cells in column A of Page.

You can fill a combo or list box with theses values using their list property.

> ComboBox1.List = getSubCategories("Sheet1")

```
Function getSubCategories(Page As String) As String()

    Dim arrSubCategories() As String
    Dim count As Long
    Dim c As Range

    With Worksheets(Page)
        For Each c In .Range("A2", .Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
            If c.Font.Bold Then
                ReDim Preserve arrSubCategories(count)
                arrSubCategories(count) = c.Value
                count = count + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With

    getSubCategories = arrSubCategories
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, the array based solution is the way to go! It made everything a lot neater prevents having to have so many variables.

Comment: Glad that I could help!

Answer (score 0):

you may find useful to have a `Range` returned with subcategories cells found:

```
Function SelectBold(Page As String, colIndex As String) As Range
    With Worksheets(Page)
        With .Range(colIndex & "1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, colIndex).End(xlUp)).Offset(, .UsedRange.Columns.Count)
            .FormulaR1C1 = "=if(isbold(RC[-1]),"""",1)"
            .Value = .Value
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) < .Rows.Count Then Set SelectBold = Intersect(.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow, .Parent.Columns(1))
            .Clear
        End With
    End With
End Function

Function IsBold(rCell As Range)
    IsBold = rCell.Font.Bold
End Function
```

to be possibly exploited as follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim subCategoriesRng As Range, cell As Range

    Set subCategoriesRng = SelectBold(Worksheets("bolds").Name, "A") '<--| pass worksheet name and column to search in

    If Not subCategoriesRng Is Nothing Then
        For Each cell In subCategoriesRng '<--| loop through subcategories cells
            '... code
        Next cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Morlo4: did you get through it?

Comment: Yeah I eventually did thanks, whilst I didn't use your solution so to speak, it did help me to understand how it worked!

Comment: Posting your solution may help other people